# Multiple Line Parsing using PyParsing

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm trying to create a message parser using the PyParsing. All the fields are separated using semicolon, but in some cases, a field can have multiple lines, as this template:

```
key 1: value ... value
key 2: value ... more
continues...
...
continues...
key 3: one line only
```

My parser for this file, is:

```
# Value Separator
colon = Literal(":").suppress()

# Line Operators
SOL = LineStart().suppress()
EOL = OneOrMore(LineEnd()).suppress()
blankline = SOL + EOL

# Values
noncolons = "".join( [ c for c in printables if c != ":" ] ) + " \t"

# General
keyDef = Word(noncolons) + colon + restOfLine
ignoreLine = SOL + Word(noncolons) + ~colon + restOfLine + EOL
parser = Dict( ZeroOrMore( Group( keyDef ) ) )
parser.ignore(blankline)
parser.ignore(ignoreLine)
```

But when I try to parse, I only got one line, for example for the second key:

```
key 2 = value ... more
```

How can I solve this problem using PyParsing?

Thank you.